# Filtering row labels in pivot table using vba

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I have searched a lot of forums but still haven't found the answer for this:

I am trying to filter my row label which varies from 1 to 10, in order to only show me 5 and 10.

I wrote the following code, but it produces error 1004 "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class".

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SideCalculations-KPIs").Activate
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ToStateId")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotItems("5").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("10").Visible = True
End With
```

thanks in advance

Comment: to check the name of the Pivotfield, in the Debug/Immediate window execute this code: `?Sheets("SideCalculations-KPIs").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(1).name` - it may be that the name **ToStateId** is wrong

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly mentioned in the error, the name of the PivotField is incorrect.

The possibility is that the Name of the Pivot Field has been changed from "ToStateId". In order to find the appropriate name, please run the following code:

```
For each pField in ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields
     Debug.Print pField.Name
Next pField
```

Go to VBA Editor, press Ctrl+G, it will open the immediate window. It will show all the available pivot fields.Then please use the correct Pivot Field and try.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
dim pvItem as pivotitem 
For Each pvtitem In Sheets("SideCalculations-KPIs").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotItems
    if (pvitem.name="5" or pvitem.name="10") then
        pvitem.visible=true
    else
        pvitem.visible=false
    end if
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much Philip, however the 4th line is producing a Syntax Error, can you guess why? thanks!

Comment: try it now, had a missing bracket

Comment: thanks for helping, i had already tried that, but the error persists

Comment: missing quote after the 10.. should be `pvtem.name="10") then`

Comment: now i am having run-time error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: i want to filter a data field in the "Report filter" and/or "Row Label". Imagine a variable varying from 1 to 10. Suppose I want to filter by the value 5. I am extracting my database from SQL using PowerPivot, depending on the choosen data range, the value=5 may not exist and it destroys my data model on subsequent analysis. Do you know a way to solve my problem? Best

Comment: Still not able to do it. Might it be because I am using PowerPivot tables? not the excel pivot table... Thanks for your help!